# What's the equivalent of Java Swing's JTabbedPane in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm going through the [reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm#class-reference) and I can't find an equivalent. Here's my simple code:

```
import traceback
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Track Editor")
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=None)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=None)
        self.file_menu.add_separator()
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
        self.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

    def main():

        app = App()
        app.mainloop()

        return 0

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I have just a window with a menu bar. Now I need to add a [tabbed pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) so that I can switch the panel's widgets according to the tab I'm in. I need a [tabbed pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), not a whole window (I don't want to use different menus for each tab). What's the equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest are going to be the [ttk.PanedWindow](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-PanedWindow.html), or the [tk.PanedWindow](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/panedwindow.html)

You could also look at the [ttk.Notebook](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Notebook.html) that has tabs.

> The purpose of a Notebook widget is to provide an area where the user
>   can select pages of content by clicking on tabs at the top of the area